# Android studio preview is not showing.

Tags: android, preview

[Android Studio problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0KRy.png)

Hi, Everyone, I am having trouble with android studio. The preview doesn't show and don't know what to do. Any ideas on what the problem is? I have attached a picture of my android studio for the link above

Comment: Looks like your gradle project sync failed.  Previews can't be shown until the project builds properly. It requires all the generated R files to be present.

Comment: Is it my windows laptop, as it says on the error message?